# The program isn't producing output rather is stuck in a loop which fades after a few seconds and prints killed?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
void show_password(){
  int i = 0;
  fstream fin;
  fin.open("pass_words",ios::in);
  while(i == 0){
    if(!fin.is_open()){
      cerr<<"File not Found\n";
    }
    else{
      break;
    }
  }
  vector<string>data1;
  string content;
  while(getline(fin,content)){
    stringstream f(content);
    string words;
    while(f,words,','){
      data1.push_back(words);
    }
  }
  cout<<data1.size()<<'\n';


  int y;
  for (int i = 0;i < data1.size();++i){

    cout<<"-"<<data1[y]<<'\n';
    ++y;

  }
}

int main()
{
  show_password();
}
```

i want this code to read the "pass_words" csv file and print the data inside it....but it is stuck in loop i don't know....the terminal doesn't show anything for few seconds and suddenly the terminal prints "Killed"....i don't know why...just for info the "pas_sword" contains:

```
hello,facebook
byebye,youtube
helloworld,instagram
```

output of terminal:

```
Killed
```

and i am using ubuntu terminal....

Comment: show whole code, it does not compile.

Comment: This is the code that I have written to read and print the data inside CSV

Comment: Good attempt!!!! I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you expect this piece of code to do:

```
stringstream f(content);
string words;
while(f,words,','){
  data1.push_back(words);
}
```

The comma operator (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other)):

> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression `E1` is evaluated, its result is discarded (although if it has class type, it won't be destroyed until the end of the containing full expression), and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression `E2` begins (note that a user-defined operator, cannot guarantee sequencing) (until C++17).

In simple terms: `while(f,words,',')` is the same as `while(',')` and because the value of `','` is different from zero, it is the same as `while(true)`. You are pushing empty strings into the vector till infinity with that loop. Not sure about the logic of your code, but for example this would extract comma separated words from `f` and push them into `data1`:

```
stringstream f(content);
string words;
while(std::getline(f,words,',')){
  data1.push_back(words);
}
```

Comment: its working but the above code is directly printing everything i want each row in the csv to print in a new line.....also this code prints the commas also....

Comment: 12345ty,facebook 098765,youtube; 2werty,whatsapp 2werty,whatsapp

Comment: this is how it prints....tell me how to print each row of csv in new line and not to print the comma

Comment: @SreeHari strictly speaking there is no quesiton in your question. I interpreted the quesiton to be "Why does this code fail?" and that is what I answered. Anyhow I edited to use `,` as delimiter instead of space

Comment: @SreeHari "as I earlier explained in the question" I am a bit confused now. The code in my answer is different from the one in your question.

Comment: .i am sorry its working perfectly....thanks for you valuable contribution.....:0